# Spring ApplicationEvent onApplicationEvent method

Tags: java, spring

Expected: When i run application in debug mode and pulling the endpoint, `bytes` still appear to be null however i did implement ApplicationEvent and passed ApplicationStartedEvent, then I have override onApplicationEvent and called my method there, which should lead to code execution once application started and `bytes` should already have a value. Have I missed something

```
public class FaqAttachment implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationStartedEvent> {

private final String fileName = "FAQ.pdf";
private byte[] bytes;

public Attachment asAttachment() {
    return new Attachment(pdfToBytes(), fileName);
}

private byte[] pdfToBytes() {
    if (bytes == null) {
        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(fileName).getFile()))) {
            this.bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {
    pdfToBytes();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
@Component
public class FaqAttachment {

    private final String fileName = "FAQ.pdf";
    private byte[] bytes;

    public Attachment asAttachment() {
        return new Attachment(pdfToBytes(), fileName);
    }

    private byte[] pdfToBytes() {
        if (bytes == null) {
            try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(fileName).getFile()))) {
                this.bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return bytes;
    }


    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationStartedEvent(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {
        pdfToBytes();
    }

}
```

Comment: i was just missing annotation so you have helped, thank you , i forgot that this should be a component in spring context for spring to proceed